# How to tell Mercurial not to look for root from ignored sub-directory

Tags: mercurial

So here's the problem. I have my configuration file in my home directory `~` under Mercurial control. Part of the

```
|-~
  |.hg/...
  |-Dev
    |-Project1/...
    |-Project2/...
  .hgrc
  .hgignore
```

I have `Dev` directory excluded from the source control in `.hgignore` file. 
However when I am in the directory `~/Dev/Project1` Mercurial thinks that I am in the under the source control. If I type `hg root` in any directory that is in the `.hgignore` or its sub-directory `hg` still considers it being a part of repository.

Is it a bug or a feature ?

**UPDATE**

So, here's the simple experiment one could do from the command line:

```
% mkdir -p /var/HgTest
% cd /var/HgTest
% hg init
% echo "this is a repository file" >> test.txt
% hg commit -Am "added repo file"
% cat <<EOT >> .hgignore
heredoc> syntax:re
heredoc>
heredoc> ^Dev
heredoc> EOT
% hg commit -Am "added .hgignore"
% echo "This is not in repository" >> Dev/notinrepo.txt
```

Now, `Dev` directory not in repository, if you type `hg st` anywhere under `/var/HgTest` it shows you that repo is clean. However if you go into `Dev` directory and type `hg root` it will output `/var/HgTest`. This is perhaps desired result. However, since the path should be ignored, I would think that hg root should effectively exit with -1 return code and message "not in repository" or something like that.

In my case, having `HOME` directory under source control effectively makes some of the tools consider every new directory (even under ignored paths) as a part of Mercurial repository located in the `HOME` directory.

Comment: It's a feature for when you are in ~/Dev/Project1/deeply/nested and want to keep mercurial commands within the scope of Project1. Workaround is to hg init in ~/dev/project1. Another bad practice is putting your home directory under VCS; I can see no benefit to be gained from it. Better to establish good snapshot backups for $HOME, even if they are stored on the same machine.

Comment: To me though it seems reasonable that paths added to `.hgignore` should be ignored.

Comment: Show me the bits of  .hgignore that pertain to this in the question body, please. Include the regime (glob or regex).

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Thanks for the well structured demo code you added. So long as there is an `.hg` repository somewhere in the tree above you, Mercurial will seek it out and read the ignore file and not take action on ignored paths. However `hg root` only looks for an `.hg` which is true, you are in the ~ repository, by definition. I don't see how it could be done otherwise; you can't find the ignore file until you've inspected the root.

Comment: @msw I think your comment deserves to become an answer - the answer

Comment: @planetmaker Thanks for the recommendation; done.

Answer (score 2):

It's a feature for when you are in `~/Dev/Project1/deeply/nested` and want to keep mercurial commands within the scope of Project1.

A workaround is to `hg init` in `~/Dev/Project1`. Part of the problem is the bad practice of putting your home directory under version control; I can see no benefit to be gained from it and much cost. As an example, almost everything you do with a browser, or music player, or many other programs is going to alter files in `~/.groovy-game/config` or `~/.browser/cache-files`; there is no meaningful way to choose a commit point. Because of this it would be better to establish good, incremental snapshot backups for `$HOME`, even if they are stored on the same machine.

This is not to say that dot-directories in your home should never be versioned. for example, suppose I hack on my `~/.vim` files because I am working on the ultimate editing environment, `cd ~/.vim; hg init` can certainly be useful.

Put another way — so long as there is an `.hg` repository somewhere in the tree above you, Mercurial will seek it out and read the ignore file and not take action on ignored paths. However, `hg root` only looks for an `.hg` directory. In your case, there is always a root, you are in your `~` repository by definition. I don't see how it could be done otherwise; you can't find the ignore file until you've inspected the root.